# UDP Packet sent not being read by server correctly

Tags: java, udp

I'm sending two packets from a client to server. The issue I'm having is the data being read on the server makes both strings the same length with regards to the longest string sent. For example:

if string 1 was : `1234`
and string 2 was: `abcdefghi`

the server would read

```
1234efghi
abcdefghi
```

It should just display

```
1234
abcdefghi
```

My code is:

```
byte[] toSendUser = new byte[1024];
byte[] toSendPass = new byte[1024];

String name = "1234";
String password = "abcdefghi"; 

    toSendUser = name.getBytes();
        toSendPass = password.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket packSend = new DatagramPacket (toSendUser, toSendUser.length, ipConn, 9876); 
        connection.send(packSend);

        DatagramPacket packSendtwo = new DatagramPacket (toSendPass, toSendPass.length, ipConn, 9876); 
        connection.send(packSendtwo);
```

Could it be a server issue or is my code wrong in my client?

Comment: Where's the question about Linux and/or Unix?

Comment: Show us the *server* code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DatagramPackets` in Java keep shrinking to the size of the smallest one received so far. You have to either create a new one per `receive(),` or at least reset the length every time before the next `receive().`